# OkHttp3 - boolean query parameter using HttpURL.Builder

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Is it possible to add boolean query parameter?

So far I have only found two methods which allow String values.

`okhttp3.HttpUrl.Builder#addQueryParameter(String key, String value)`
`okhttp3.HttpUrl.Builder#addEncodedQueryParameter(String key, String value)`

Is there any way we can do

```
 HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = requestURL.newBuilder();
 urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("test", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the API of `OkHttp`. It accepts only `String` values.

This method can be an acceptable workaround:

```
Boolean.TRUE.toString();
```